# float [] array problem in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am coding in xcode by objective c. I came up with a problem. 
I want to try like

```
declare float[] weights;
```

results looks like this

```
weight[0] = 0.5
weight[1] = 0.4
weight[2] = 0.9
```

A.h

```
NSMutableArray *weight;
```

A.m

```
weights = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    float randomNumber = arc4random() % 11;
    [weights addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:randomNumber]];
    NSLog(@" for loops color prob weghts=%f",[weights objectAtIndex:i] );

}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code. Please help me to find out?

When I print it by NSLOG " all [weight = 0.000]  and also How do I access like [weight floatvalue].

secondly, when I create this class to another class there are weight [0],[1],[2],[3] and no values

Comment: I think in A.h is NSMutableArray *weights;

Answer (score 3):

It should be `[[weights objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]` when you print it in your NSLog

Comment: could you please try to answer me second question.

Comment: oops. did not read your last line. Can you explain that part? What do you wish to do?

Comment: second question> when I create this class from other class like [[A alloc] init] and then look at the inside values in weights. I can see the weight[0],[1],[2],[3] and each value by'ox99333' has similar numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry. can you post some code about this second part with the output that you expect and the output you are getting? I'm unable to clearly understand this part.

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber is a class, not a integral type.

Therefore, you must use %@, not %f.

```
NSLog(@" for loops color prob weghts=%@",[weights objectAtIndex:i] );
```

Alternatively, use floatValue, like you said. You may need to cast the object into NSNumber first (for type safety)

```
NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)[weights objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@" for loops color prob weghts=%f", [number floatValue]);
```

Also, you are leaking objects here, because you did not release them after putting them in the array. Either release after placing them in array, or use [NSNumber numberWithFloat:]

Comment: You can use +[NSMutableArray array]. NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray so you can use all the class methods declared there.

Comment: I thought NSMutableArray was the superclass of NSArray? lol thank you.